# Jquery function doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

My page protection JS file looks like that

```
(function($){
$.fn.disableSelection = function() {
    return this.each(function() {           
        $(this).attr('unselectable', 'on')
               .css({
                   '-moz-user-select':'none',
                   '-webkit-user-select':'none',
                   'user-select':'none',
                   '-ms-user-select':'none'
               })
               .each(function() {
                   this.onselectstart = function() { return false; };
               });
    });
};
})(jQuery);

var message="Bu səhifədən material kopyalamaq qadağandır!"; 

function clickIE4(){
    if (event.button==2){
        alert(message);
        return false;
    }
}
function clickNS4(e){
    if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
        if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
            alert(message);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
if (document.layers){
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
    document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
} else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
    document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}
document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
```

All functions work well except $.fn.disableSelection . It must disable selection. But I can select any piece of text. What am I missing?

Comment: The function 'document.layers' is deprecated since Netscape Navigator 6 has been published. This browser died in the first years of new century. So you can remove this from your code.

Comment: Why engage with this anti-user technique? if you serve it through HTTP, it's trivial to copy and has a tendency to irritate those over a minimal level of competence.

Answer (score 1):

You only define the function in this code. Execute the function.